# pandas.merge adding _x and _y to merged variables in IPython notebook but not Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I've got two dataframes, `internetuserate_train1` and `merged_train`, which both contain the series `internetuserate`. When I perform

```
merged_train_all = pd.merge(internetuserate_train1, merged_train, on='index')
```

in Anaconda - Spyder, the resulting `merged_train_all` dataframe has the series `internetuserate`, but when I perform the exact same command in an IPython notebook, the resulting dataframe does not have `internetuserate` but instead `internetuserate_x` and `internetuserate_y`. This causes the rest of my code to fail. The Spyder behavior is what I expect and I want the same behavior in IPython. What is going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: Have you checked the `head`s of both dataframes in each environment? Are they really identical and have the same columns? Do you use the same version of `pandas` in both environents?

Comment: @DYZ I just installed the full Anaconda package last week, which included both Spyder and IPython, so I'm assuming it's the same pandas version, but I'm not sure how to check. I'm looking at the heads and it seems that in Spyder, the `merged_train` dataframe doesn't contain the series `internetuserate` but the series does exist in that dataframe in IPython... I'm really confused by that.

Comment: You may have some subtle data differences in memory from a previous run. Recall objects persist in these tools. Consider clean sessions and running exact code and data sources. And what does the actual .py at command line (no notebooks or consoles) show?

Comment: Look at `pandas.__version__` in both environments. Are they the same? Please add the values of `merged_train.columns` and `internetuserate_train1.columns` in both environnents to your question.

Comment: I think @Parfait was onto something, because this morning when I fired up my computer I couldn't replicate the issue. It seems to have worked itself out.